# How to solve SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder" in Eclipse Tycho RCP

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp, tycho

I'm using Eclipse 2022-03.

I got two types of error messages after an update of a third party library.

1)
[image: Missing contraints]

This type of error I solved by 'Add required plug-ins' in the Run and Debug configurations. The plug-in org.slf4j.api (1.7.30.v20200204-2150) solved the problem. Unfortunately I have to do 'Add required plug-ins' each time I start up Eclipse.

Any idea how I can get 'Add required plug-ins' to stick between restarts of Eclipse?

2)
[image: SLF4J: Failed to load class]

Same error occurs for my headless build:
[image]

What is the way to solve the classic error message "SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder"" in a Eclipse Tycho RCP project?

According to http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder I need to download an implementation (JAR file) of the slf4j-api and put it in the classpath.

a)
Where can I find a typical slf4j-api implementation to use in my project?

b)
Where shall integrate that API implementation (JAR file) in my Eclipse Tycho RCP project so it works both for head and headless builds?

My Eclipse RCP Tycho project is using a target-platform definition:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<?pde version="3.8"?>
<target name="target-platform" sequenceNumber="1">
    <locations>
        <location includeAllPlatforms="false" includeConfigurePhase="true" includeMode="planner" includeSource="true" type="InstallableUnit">
            <repository location="http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.23"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.equinox.sdk.feature.group" version="3.23.300.v20220223-1131"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.platform.ide" version="4.23.0.I20220308-0310"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.platform.sdk" version="4.23.0.I20220308-0310"/>
        </location>
        <location includeAllPlatforms="false" includeConfigurePhase="true" includeMode="planner" includeSource="true" type="InstallableUnit">
            <repository location="https://download.eclipse.org/tools/orbit/downloads/drops/R20220302172233/repository"/>
            <unit id="org.junit" version="4.13.2.v20211018-1956"/>
            <unit id="org.junit.jupiter.api" version="5.8.1.v20211018-1956"/>
            <unit id="org.junit.jupiter.engine" version="5.8.1.v20211018-1956"/>
            <unit id="org.slf4j.binding.simple" version="1.7.30.v20200204-2150"/>
            <unit id="org.slf4j.binding.simple.source" version="1.7.30.v20200204-2150"/>
        </location>
        <location includeAllPlatforms="false" includeConfigurePhase="true" includeMode="planner" includeSource="true" type="InstallableUnit">
            <repository location="https://download.eclipse.org/nattable/releases/2.0.2/repository/"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.nattable.core.feature.feature.group" version="2.0.2.202111300816"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.nattable.extension.e4.feature.feature.group" version="2.0.2.202111300816"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.nattable.extension.glazedlists.feature.feature.group" version="2.0.2.202111300816"/>
        </location>
        <location includeAllPlatforms="false" includeConfigurePhase="true" includeMode="planner" includeSource="true" type="InstallableUnit">
            <repository location="https://download.eclipse.org/justj/jres/17/updates/release/17.0.2"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.justj.openjdk.hotspot.jre.full.feature.group" version="17.0.2.v20220201-1208"/>
        </location>
    </locations>
</target>
```

This is my POM:

```
<project>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>vcs</groupId>
    <artifactId>vcs.root</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <properties>
        <tycho.version>2.7.1</tycho.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
                <artifactId>tycho-p2-director-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${tycho.version}</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
                <artifactId>tycho-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${tycho.version}</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-toolchains-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>toolchain</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <toolchains>
                        <jdk>
                            <version>17.0.2</version>
                            <vendor>Eclipse Adoptium</vendor>
                        </jdk>
                        <jdk>
                            <version>11.0.15</version>
                            <vendor>Eclipse Adoptium</vendor>
                        </jdk>
                        <jdk>
                            <version>18.0.1</version>
                            <vendor>Eclipse Adoptium</vendor>
                        </jdk>
                    </toolchains>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
                <artifactId>target-platform-configuration</artifactId>
                <version>${tycho.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <executionEnvironment>org.eclipse.justj.openjdk.hotspot.jre.full-17</executionEnvironment>
                    <target>
                        <artifact>
                            <groupId>vcs</groupId>
                            <artifactId>target-platform</artifactId>
                            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
                        </artifact>
                    </target>
                    <environments>
                        <environment>
                            <os>win32</os>
                            <ws>win32</ws>
                            <arch>x86_64</arch>
                        </environment>
                    </environments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <modules>
        <module>bundles</module>
        <module>features</module>
        <module>releng</module>
        <module>tests</module>
    </modules>
</project>
```

Here is the list of installed software in Eclipse:
[image: Installed software]

Here is my product definition:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?pde version="3.5"?>

<product name="ReqTool" uid="reqtool" id="info.wallberg.reqtool.userinterface.plugin.product" application="org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt.E4Application" version="0.0.1" useFeatures="true" includeLaunchers="true">

   <configIni use="default">
   </configIni>

   <launcherArgs>
      <programArgs>-clearPersistedState
-console
      </programArgs>
      <vmArgsMac>-XstartOnFirstThread -Dorg.eclipse.swt.internal.carbon.smallFonts
      </vmArgsMac>
   </launcherArgs>

   <windowImages/>

   <launcher>
      <win useIco="false">
         <bmp/>
      </win>
   </launcher>

   <vm>
   </vm>

   <plugins>
   </plugins>

   <features>
      <feature id="info.wallberg.library.jre.win32.x86_64"/>
      <feature id="info.wallberg.library.fileextractor.feature"/>
      <feature id="info.wallberg.library.oscommand.feature"/>
      <feature id="info.wallberg.library.pdfextractor.feature"/>
      <feature id="info.wallberg.reqtool.requirementmodel.feature"/>
      <feature id="info.wallberg.reqtool.requirementservice.cursorial.feature"/>
      <feature id="info.wallberg.reqtool.userinterface.feature"/>
      <feature id="org.eclipse.e4.rcp" installMode="root"/>
      <feature id="org.eclipse.emf.ecore" installMode="root"/>
      <feature id="org.eclipse.emf.common" installMode="root"/>
      <feature id="org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.nattable.core.feature" installMode="root"/>
      <feature id="org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.nattable.extension.glazedlists.feature" installMode="root"/>
   </features>

   <configurations>
      <plugin id="org.apache.felix.scr" autoStart="true" startLevel="2" />
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.core.runtime" autoStart="true" startLevel="0" />
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.equinox.common" autoStart="true" startLevel="2" />
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.equinox.event" autoStart="true" startLevel="2" />
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator" autoStart="true" startLevel="1" />
   </configurations>

   <preferencesInfo>
      <targetfile overwrite="false"/>
   </preferencesInfo>

   <cssInfo>
      <file path="/info.wallberg.reqtool.userinterface.plugin/css/default.css"/>
   </cssInfo>

</product>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That depends on how you want to add logging support to your application. If you don't care about logging you can either ignore the warning or add the nop logger or simple logger from eclipse Orbit. The NatTable examples are using the simple binding for example. The target definition consumes the SLF4J binding from Orbit, the E4 example feature includes the bundle.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I appreciate it very much.

Comment: The problem is that I'm relatively new to RCP development and Eclipse as such.
As far as I can see in Eclipse I have already installed a simple logger. Looking in the list of installed plugins I can see org.slf4j.binding.simple, so I don't understand what I need to do more to get it right. Should I add something in my target definition as well?

Comment: Yes. The Eclipse IDE you are using is one thing. If you are developing your application against a target platform, it will resolve and build only what is part of the target platform, not of what is available in your Eclipse installation. This makes it possible to build on a server where no Eclipse IDE installation is available.

Comment: Thanks. I get the picture, but for some reason I'm still unable to get it right. I have updated the target platform definition with a SLF4J Simple Binding (see above) but I still have the same warnings. What is it I'm missing here?

Comment: Have you added the SLF4J Simple Binding to your product? As you have features it needs to be added to one of them.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I have added the SLF4J Simple Binding to one of my features (info.wallberg.reqtool.userinterface.feature). That made the warnings disappeare when I run from the IDE, but my Maven/Tycho build still generates the warnings. I can't understand why since the target-platform has the binding added and the same feature is built.

Comment: You probably see the warning from Tycho. That is an issue in Tycho itself and not an issue of your product build.

Comment: Again, thanks a lot for teaching me. Much appreciated. I upgraded Tycho to 2.7.4 but there was no difference. I saw a discussion about that issue on the net. Perhaps we will see a fix in 3.0?

Comment: AFAIK the fix is applied and will be part of 3.0

Comment: @DirkFauth When will Tycho 3.0 be released?

Comment: Looks like end of this week https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/technology.tycho/releases/3.0.0